"Option type"-esque deserialization of API response in .NET Core
I'm using .NET's native JSON utilities (System.Text) to perform automatic Serialization/Deserialization of data going to and from an API. The API responses are structured like the following:
{
   "response-type": {
        "some-data-field" {
            "some-data": {
                ...
            }
        },
        "some-other-data-field": {
            "some-other-data": {
                ...
            }
        },
        "errors": {
            "error": {
                "name": string
                "message": string
            }
        }
    }
}

I can create a ResponseModel to capture said fields:
public record ResponseModel : ErrorableResponse
{
    public ResponseModelDataField SomeDataField { get; set; }
    public record ResponseModelDataField 
    {
        ...
    }
}

For the most part this is working very well. I initialize the Serializer scoped to the API/service and use the serializer on each serialization/deserialization:
private readonly JsonSerializerOptions serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.KebabCaseLower,
        Converters =
        {
            new JsonStringEnumConverter()
        },
        WriteIndented = true,
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    };
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseModel>(responseBody, serializerOptions);

Here's the problem: error can be both an object with an error name and message or a List of objects with a name and message. But the response ALWAYS comes back as a 200, so there's no way for me to check whether or not to expect errors (and use a different ResponseModel) until I can actually parse the deserialized model.
I'm completely lost w.r.t how to handle this without writing a custom converter for Json Serialization/Deserialization (which I desperately don't want to do).
Is there a way to naively parse the response and tell the native converter to coerce that property into either an object or a list of said objects?
What is the ".NET" approach to handling this?
EDIT: I also realized I can probably try {} catch {} every deserialization but I'd prefer to not have to do that on every single request for both performance and sanity.

Arguably writing converter here is the way to go. And it should not be that cumbersome - please check out this answer.

Another approach can be using JsonElement for the property type and manually processing it or using the approach with JsonExtensionData

@GuruStron thanks for pointing in both directions. I had looked at implementing a converter but any implementation I came across looked way too complex for me to want to use it as a first resort. I will circle back and dig deeper tho.

to set a differrent output - check discriminated unions, to hva serialization errors why not to use newtonsoft?  var errors = new List();
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
Error = (s, e) =>
{
var _Obj = e.CurrentObject as Row;
if (_Obj != null)
{
errors.Add($"Error on {_Obj.ColumnName}: {e.ErrorContext.Error.Message}");
}
else
{
errors.Add(e.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
}
e.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
}
};
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, settings).Dump();

Does How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using System.Text.Json? answer your question?  You would apply [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<Error>))] to your public List<Error> Error { get; set; } = new() property.
